# Core dumped while passing double array from C to python using c extension module for python

Tags: python, c, wrapper, ctypes, numpy-ndarray

I am writing a simple c code that will return a double array to python. I compiled the code successfully with out error and can generate `.so` file to import in python. However when I call the wrapped C function from Python environment I get `core dump`. I am attaching the c code below so that the error can be reproduced. I would be highly obliged if anyone directs me to point me to understand where am I going wrong which results in `core dump` error? While debuging I found that the source of the error is in the line

```
pyArr = (PyArrayObject*) PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(2, dims, NPY_DOUBLE, ptr);
```

yet I am unable to fix the issue. I also tried with `static double array` in `line 6` but got same `core dump` issue.   Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include <numpy/ndarrayobject.h>

extern "C" {
    static PyObject* func_wrap(PyObject* , PyObject* args)
    {
    double* ptr;
    ptr = (double *) malloc(4 * sizeof(double));
    *ptr = 1.0; *(ptr+1) = 2.0; *(ptr+2) = 3.0; *(ptr+3) = 4.0;
    PyArrayObject* pyArr;
    npy_intp dims[1];
    dims[0] = 4;
    pyArr = (PyArrayObject*)PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_BYTE, ptr);
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS(pyArr, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);  /* numpy array takes the ownership afterwards */
    return Py_BuildValue("O", pyArr);
 }

 static PyMethodDef CppMethods[] = {
      {"func", func_wrap, METH_VARARGS, "returns numpy 1d array"},
      {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
  };

 // Define module information
 static struct PyModuleDef mydemo = {
 PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
 "mydemo",
 "mydemo Module",
 -1,
 CppMethods
 };

 // Init function for module
 PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_mydemo(void) {
     import_array();
     return PyModule_Create(&mydemo);
 }
}
```

Comment: Your data array is allocated on the stack, so it goes out of scope once the function finishes. This leaves Python pointing at data that no longer exists. As a quick fix, you can try `static double data[4] = { ... }` instead.

Comment: Hi Hitobat, I tried using `static` array as you mentioned but the core dumped issue still persists. I even tried allocating memory with `malloc` but still got the same error. Although data array getting out of scope as the function finishes is logical to think, I suspect that there is some problem in writing data in `pyArr`. I have updated the code with `malloc` implementation to hold memory for data array which also produces `core dumped` problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The dims arg to `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` makes it look like you need a 2d array. Specifically for your example, something where `ptr[0][0]=1` and `ptr[0][3]=4`. Please try wrapping the current ptr array with another array and see if this works? Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Thank you for reaching back. I have updated the code which uses 1D array now to avoid confusion. However the same problem still exists.

Comment: I have found that I was missing `import_array()` method in `PyMODINIT_FUNC`. This solved my problem.

Comment: I don't get any `core dump` error; however the result is an array of zeros `[0., 0., 0., 0.]`, which is expected since you declared `NPY_BYTE` as the type of the array. You should use `NPY_DOUBLE` instead.